# Converting c# to VB.NET for my windows phone app

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I am trying to convert a piece of C# code to VB.NET to get my app to work but i am getting an error. The piece of code that was originally C# is:

```
        private void loginBrowserControl_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Uri.ToString().StartsWith(AppSettings.CallbackUri))
        {
            var AuthorizeResult = MainUtil.GetQueryParameters(e.Uri.ToString());
            var VerifyPin = AuthorizeResult["oauth_verifier"];
            this.loginBrowserControl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            var AccessTokenQuery = OAuthUtil.GetAccessTokenQuery(OAuthTokenKey, tokenSecret, VerifyPin);

            AccessTokenQuery.QueryResponse += new EventHandler<WebQueryResponseEventArgs>(AccessTokenQuery_QueryResponse);
            AccessTokenQuery.RequestAsync(AppSettings.AccessTokenUri, null);
        }
    }
```

I have now converted it to VB.NET so i have:

```
    Private Sub loginBrowserControl_Navigating(sender As Object, e As NavigatingEventArgs)
    If e.Uri.ToString().StartsWith(AppSettings.AppSettings.CallbackUri) Then
        Dim AuthorizeResult = MainUtil.MainUtil.GetQueryParameters(e.Uri.ToString())
        Dim VerifyPin = AuthorizeResult("oauth_verifier")
        Me.LoginBrowserControl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
        Dim AccessTokenQuery = OAuthUtil.GetAccessTokenQuery(OAuthTokenKey, tokenSecret, VerifyPin)

        AccessTokenQuery.QueryResponse += New EventHandler(Of WebQueryResponseEventArgs)(AddressOf AccessTokenQuery_QueryResponse)
        AccessTokenQuery.RequestAsync(AppSettings.AppSettings.AccessTokenUri, Nothing)
    End If
End Sub
```

However it does not like AccessTokenQuery.QueryResponse as it gives the error 'Public Event QueryResponse(sender As Object, e As Hammock.Web.WebQueryResponseEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

What do i need to change this to?
'

Comment: try using -AddHandler AccessTokenQuery.QueryResponse, AddressOf AccessTokenQuery_QueryResponse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for adding an event handler in VB.net would be:

```
AddHandler AccessTokenQuery.QueryResponse, AddressOf AccessTokenQuery_QueryResponse
```

Comment: Okay i see where you are coming from but what would i need to do about the part of code between query response and address of? As in the bit that says '+= New EventHandler(Of WebQueryResponseEventArgs)'

Comment: That is not necessary in VB.NET. This will just work in VB

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general solution: compile your code in debug mode, then decompile it to another language with a tool like Reflector. That's the charm of .NET.